# Pagination via $_POST['paged']

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm using wordpress ajax to retrieve paginated posts...however regardless of pass **$_POST['paged']** or **$_GET['paged']** the

> get_query_var('paged')

doesn't seem to be populated...is "paged" part of the *public variables* by wordpress?

Comment: You mention `$_POST['paged']` and `$_GET['paged']`. Are you making a request that actually contains a `paged` value? Or are you trying to set `$_POST['paged']` or `$_GET['paged']` directly (e.g., `$_POST['paged'] = 'foo';`)?

Comment: @EdCottrell no i'm posting and getting via ajax